# Compare two lists via LINQ in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
if (!list.SequenceEqual(new TESTList()))
{
     MessageBox.Show("updated");
}
```

Pretty much this code does not seem to work.

I have a class as so;

```
class TESTList
{
private bool test;
}
```

Now, assuming my code all works and list is properly created, how can I determine if the two lists are the same by checking each item in the list (its boolean) and determing overall taht if both items (ex. item1 list1 and item1 list2) have same booleans, then both lists same.

I don't know.

Comment: Do both lists contain `TESTlist` items, or is one plain boolean or something else?

Comment: both contain TESTlist items!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful with `Enumerable.Zip` recommendation as it can result in `true` where the 2 input sequences are of different lengths but match up to the point where the shorter sequence ends. It will even result in `true` if one of the sequences is empty and the other is not!

`result` here will be `true`:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

bool result = Enumerable.Zip(list1, list2, (left, right) => left == right).All(x => x);
```

---

Instead you might want to use [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
bool result = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
```

Results:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

> TRUE

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

> FALSE

If you require a result of `true` when the sequences contain the same elements in any order you need to sort both sequences before comparing them:

```
bool result = list1.OrderBy (l => l).SequenceEqual(list2.OrderBy (l => l));
```

You should note that `SequenceEqual` uses the default equality comparer for the type inside the list.  This will work out of the box for a `bool` but you may need to [override Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) if your list contains a custom class which is only differentiated by a private field (I suspect your final code won't really look like that).

Answer (score 2):

```
bool result = Enumerable.Zip(list1, list2, (left, right) => left == right).All(x => x);
```

Comment: is this a boolean return? wut?

Comment: and returns true if same?

Comment: Your OP question makes no sense. However yes it returns true when they are the same https://dotnetfiddle.net/SAwIN1

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is a custom class (and what's more, the `test` field is private), there's no possible way as written for LINQ to check equality properly, so it would need to fall back on reference-equality, where the same memory addresses are being pointed to by each list. There's no particular reason to suppose this to be the case.

You'll need to implement a custom `Equals` method in `TESTlist`, therefore. (Untested.)

```
  public overrides bool Equals(object other) {
    var tlo = other as TESTlist;
    if (tlo != null) {
      return tlo.test == this.test;
    }
    else {
      return false;     // It's not a TESTlist, it can't be equal
    }
  }
```